# Solution to a Non-separable Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{xt}{x+t}$.

Can anyone give me any hints how to start? It seems that common tricks such as separation of variable, integrating factor, etc. can't be applied to this question.

Comment: This equation is not one of the standard solvable types, ODE handbooks do not list it either, so I doubt that it is analytically solvable.

Comment: @Conifold Thanks for your comment; this is actually one of the homework problems I encountered, and now I highly doubt that my instructor made a typo. I'll further consult him I guess.